# In Jena API, how to make add addLiteral fater?

Tags: jena, ontology

I am using Jena as a reasoner. My model is ,

OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);

I should update 150 literals in xsd:double of 150 individuals. I tried to use,

```
double value = ... (from other source)
Resource subject = infmodel.getResource(base + data.getId());
infmodel.addLiteral(subject, hasMeasurement, value);
```

I found the process is very slow -- it cost about 4 seconds. I think Jena made reasoning every time when a value was updated.

Anybody know how to close the reasoning until all values updated?

Thank you!

Comment: Inside yours OntModel there is a `org.apache.jena.reasoner.InfGraph` with a Reasoner attached. You can get raw data graph from it, and wrap it as another model, then add any triples, then re-bind new data to the original ont-model, if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Or, create a model with no reasoning, make all changes required, then create a model with reasoning based on it.